# How to extract Oracle DML (insert,update) queries from a dump file?

Tags: linux, shell-script, scripting, sql

Example:

```
$cat data.txt

SCN           THREAD  OPERATION ID                                       OBJECT ID   OBJECT NAME                     REPLICATE  OPERATION       SQL
------------- ------- -------------------------------------------------- ----------- ------------------------------- ---------- --------------- -------------------------------------------------
959936598838  1       0x00df.80ae1336.0000:0001.001087a6.00074e62.0010   0           N/A                             NO         START           set transaction read write;
959936598838  1       0x00df.80ae1336.0000:0001.001087a6.00074e62.0010   8144610     HEARTBEAT                       YES        INSERT          insert into "SRS"."HEARTBEAT"("INST_NAME","CR_DATE") values ('LIVE LIVE-22.',TO_DATE('03/15/2019 23:00:05', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'));
959936598839  1       0x00df.80ae1337.0000:0001.001087a6.00074e63.0174   0           N/A                             NO         COMMIT          commit;
```

From the above file, is it possible to extract the insert query including values using shell scripting?

i need desired output like below.

insert into "SRS"."HEARTBEAT"("INST_NAME","CR_DATE") values ('LIVE LIVE-22.',TO_DATE('03/15/2019 23:00:05', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'));

Comment: Did you add the `**` around the insert query, or does your data show up like that?

Comment: Please also [edit your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/523267/edit) to show your desired output.

Comment: No. data not contain any ** before and afterthe query.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming no space in the first seven columns.

```
$ while read a b c d e f g query; do echo "${query}"; done < data.txt | grep -Ei "insert|update"
insert into "SRS"."HEARTBEAT"("INST_NAME","CR_DATE") values ('LIVE LIVE-22.',TO_DATE('03/15/2019 23:00:05', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'));


$ awk '/insert|update/{for(i=1;i<=7;i++){$i=""}print}' data.txt
       insert into "SRS"."HEARTBEAT"("INST_NAME","CR_DATE") values ('LIVE LIVE-22.',TO_DATE('03/15/2019 23:00:05', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'));
```

Comment: Hi,above is just an example.the file contains  hundreds of such insert and update queries.i want to extract all of them

Comment: did you execute the given two commands ? whats the problem with given commands ?

Comment: Hi Sir,The query is working fine and im getting desired output.thank you..